# Using QTcreator 4.71 how do i turn of its advices in the code window?

Tags: qt, qt5, editor

Just starting cpp with an older version of QT creator how can I turn off the code analyze suggestions inside the area where I type my code.
(ea disable temporarily on /of setting or so).

Answer (score 1):

Options > Text Editor > Display > Line annotations (lower part): and then uncheck it.